# Wireless Adapter Not supporting with 14.04

Tags: wireless

In my desktop no other USB wireless adapter supports except tp link wn721n. Even tried to install drivers from additional driver but nothing showing in that. 
I Have tried with Iball 150 mini and Livetech wireless adapters. Pls assist me for this....

Comment: the ouput of `lspci | grep -i net` and `lsusb`  (plug in usb-wifi)